# Why does my activities change to meaningless word?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run some of my projects, android studio says

> Default Activity not found.

I check java code and some of activities change to meaningless word like this:

```xml
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Gradle: com.android.support:support-v4-24.2.1">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/24.2.1/res" />
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/24.2.1/jars/classes.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

How Can I fix this??? Thanks...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java and xml files corrupted by weird XML in Android Studio(3.2.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098150/java-and-xml-files-corrupted-by-weird-xml-in-android-studio3-2-1)